# xmlHttp, XML request,asp

Tags: xml, serverxmlhttp

Just to confirm
When sending XML data with asp  to https://www .site.com  I am getting
msxml3.dll (0x80072F0C)
A certificate is required to complete client authentication
I Talk to https://www .site.com  IT and they said that they don't have to provide any certificate to install.
IS it correct?

here is the function

Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
xmlhttp.open "POST", url, false 
'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "CONTENT_TYPE", "text/xml" 
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xhtml+xml"
'"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
xmlhttp.send docSubmit

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302080

"To make any SSL requests from the Web server, ServerXMLHTTP expects a client digital certificate to be installed, **even if the target Web server does not require a client certificate.**"