# serverXMLHTTP connection timeout on windows 2016

Tags: asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

Now this is puzzling me 2 days, I am using classic ASP to connect to XML on my server. I've had 2003 and 2008 and 2012 before, it worked.

This is my code:

```
    Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    url="http://www.server.com/xyz.asp"
    objXmlHttp.open "GET", url, False
    objXmlHttp.Send
```

If I coonect to the http version of the file xyz.asp, I get error: The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect. ??? I don't even try to use https, I call the script on http page and connect to http page.

If I use https, that means if call my page on https (I have valid certificate) and try to connect with xmlhttp object everything stalls and I get timeout on .send.

Any ideas? This happens on Windows 2016. But it seems the problem is the xyz.asp (xml file), I can open it from the URL and XML code shows with no problem, but the serverXMLHTTP doesn't like it. If I connect to the file on the old server 2012, it works ok...

How can I even snoop on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you try a more recent version of ServerXmlHttp?

```
Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

you may also want to look at:

[Can't use HTTPS with ServerXMLHTTP object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212985/cant-use-https-with-serverxmlhttp-object)

[VBA ServerXMLHTTP https request with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573022/vba-serverxmlhttp-https-request-with-self-signed-certificate)