# CURL request in classic ASP

Tags: curl, vbscript, asp-classic

Can someone help me to create classic asp code from the CURL request below?

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token f2210dacd9c6ccb8133606d94ff8e61d99b477fd' "https://cloud.seafile.com/api2/beshared-repos/"
```

I tried the sample code below, but it didn't work.

```
Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim url: url = "https://cloud.seafile.com/api2/beshared-repos/"

Dim data: data = "token=f2210dacd9c6ccb8133606d94ff8e61d99b477fd"

With http
  Call .Open("GET", url, False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token f2210dacd9c6ccb8133606d94ff8e61d99b477fd")
  Call .Send()
End With

If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then
  'Request succeeded with a HTTP 2xx response, do something...
Else
  'Output error
  Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
End If
```

And it throws the below error message at line Call.Send()

> WinHttp.WinHttpRequest error '80090326'
>
> The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

Comment: [Documentation](https://manual.seafile.com/develop/web_api.html#shared-libraries) for reference.

Comment: [Looks like my code that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462944/692942). It definitely works so if you’re getting an error its likely because your not passing the correct `Content-Type` or missing some requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the code, I've just tested your `curl` call with version 7.56.0 and here are the results;

First I tried the command in your question, which failed;

```
>curl -H 'Authorization: Token f2210dacd9c6ccb8133606d94ff8e61d99b477fd' "https://cloud.seafile.com/api2/beshared-repos/"  

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: f2210dacd9c6ccb8133606d94ff8e61d99b477fd'
curl: (35) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
```

I guessed it didn't like the single quotes used for the HTTP Authorization header so replaced them and got this;

```
>curl -H "Authorization: Token f2210dacd9c6ccb8133606d94ff8e61d99b477fd" "https://cloud.seafile.com/api2/beshared-repos/"  

curl: (35) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
```

The problem here is the error:

> schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.

which will happen regardless of what method you use to call the API.

Checking the address

```
https://cloud.seafile.com/api2/beshared-repos/
```

in a browser leads to a warning that the site is not secure in Google Chrome and using an [SSL checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://cloud.seafile.com/api2/beshared-repos/) it appears the names do not match on the SSL certificate.

> *None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (cloud.seafile.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. [Learn more about name mismatch errors](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-name-mismatch-error.html).*

Comment: Thank you @Lankymart for the feedback, the issue was with the SSL certificate!

Comment: how u passed SSL certificate can u paste command here please @Lucy

Comment: @sudhirtataraju maybe this will help [Can't use HTTPS with ServerXMLHTTP object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47356036). If not suggest posting a new question.