# vbscript xmlhttp A certificate is required to complete client authentication

Tags: paypal, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, certificate, authorization

I am trying to get the Paypal Access Token using what I believe to be the cURL equivalent in VBS.
Here is the cURL post I am trying to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/
and this is the VBScript code I am using

```
<%
    Dim Base64, ClientID, Secret 
    ClientID    = "ClientID" 
    Secret      = "Secret" 
    Base64      = "Base64" 
    Dim XMLHTTP : Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
    XMLHTTP.setOption 2, 13056 
    XMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", False, ClientID, Secret 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json" 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en_US" 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64 
    XMLHTTP.Send("grant_type=client_credentials")
```

The error that the server returns is :

```
msxml6.dll error '80072f0c'

A certificate is required to complete client authentication

Paypal.asp, line 13
```

I know there is a `XMLHTTP.setOption 3, "LOCAL_MACHINE\My\api.sandbox.paypal.com"` that can also be added to the code but from what I can see within the documentation I shouldn't need to install any certs on the server.

#### [ edit ]

This is the code [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212985/cant-use-https-with-serverxmlhttp-object/47356036#47356036) that explains how this fix works. You can use your own cert it does not need to be a self signed cert, the important part is to use **Step 2. Assign permissions to the certificate** to give the web server permission to use that certificate.

```
<%
    Dim Base64, ClientID, Secret 
    ClientID    = "ClientID" 
    Secret      = "Secret" 
    Base64      = "Base64" 
    Dim XMLHTTP : Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
    XMLHTTP.setOption 2, 13056 
    XMLHTTP.setOption 3, "LOCAL_MACHINE\My\example.za.live" ' **Added** 
    XMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", False, ClientID, Secret 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json" 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en_US" 
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64 
    XMLHTTP.Send("grant_type=client_credentials")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use HTTPS with ServerXMLHTTP object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47356036/2069605) (second answer)

Comment: Thanks @PrestonPHX this worked perfectly for me, I just made an edit to the above so to that others can see how the fixed code works.